# Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny continue when any task finish without exception

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have 3 tasks in my application that are responsible for getting data from databases.
Till now I had all tasks executed one after one. If first finished and had Result then this was my data, if now I started second task and I checked again.

Recently I found information that I can start multiple tasks and continue when one of them finish using `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny`. This works fine if all my task don't throw any Exceptions, but if any Task fails I can't get results I want.

For example:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return 1;
});

var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    throw new Exception("My error");
    return 2;
});

var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    return 3;
});

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] {t1, t2,t3}, (t) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
});
```

This code starts 3 tasks and waits till one of them finish.
Because `t2` throws exception after 2 seconds it is the one that is available in `ContinueWhenAny`.

From code above I would like to get 3 in `t.Result`.
Is there an option to continue only when task finished successfully? Something like `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAnyButSkipFailedTasks`

**EDIT 1**
This is my solution for now based on @Nitram answer:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(5,15)*1000);
    throw new Exception("My error");
    return 1;
});

var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    throw new Exception("My error");
    return 2;
});

var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    throw new Exception("My error");
    return 3;
});

var tasks = new List<Task<int>> { t1, t2, t3 };

Action<Task<int>> handler = null;

handler = t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        tasks.Remove(t);
        if (tasks.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("No data at all!");
        }
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks.ToArray(), handler);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    }
};

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks.ToArray(), handler);
```

What I need now is how to throw exception when all tasks throw exception?
Maybe this can be changed into single method that would return task - something like child tasks?

Comment: I think you need to write your own Task.WhenAny version that takes a Func<Task, bool> that specifies whether this particular task completion is supposed to complete the WhenAny.

Answer (score 3):

There is a overload to the [`ContinueWhenAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321277(v=vs.110).aspx) function that does what you want.

Simply set the `TaskContinuationOptions` to `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` and the failed tasks will be ignored.

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] {t1, t2,t3}, (t) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

So we concluded that this answer is actually wrong.

The removal of the tasks from a list seems to be the only way I can think of.
I tried to put this into some lines of code. Here you go:

```
var tasks = new List<Task> {t1, t2, t3};

Action<Task> handler = null;
handler = (Task t) =>
{
    if (t.IsFauled) {
        tasks.Remove(t);
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks.ToArray, handler);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    }
};
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks.ToArray, handler);
```

I am not very firm with C#, but I hope it gives you a idea. What is basically happening is that every time a task that is faulted is handled, this task is removed from the list of known tasks and the function waits for the next one.

Okay and now the entire thing with .NET 4.5 and the `async`-`await` pattern.
`await` basically gives you the ability to register what ever is written after the await into a continuation.

So this is nearly the same pattern with `async`-`await`.

```
var tasks = new List<Task> {t1, t2, t3};
while (tasks.Any()) 
{
    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    if (finishedTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    }
    else
    {
        var result = await finishedTask;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        return;
    }
}
```

The only difference is that the outer function needs to be a `async` function for that one. This means upon encountering the first `await` the outer function will return the `Task` that holds the continuation.

You can add a surrounding function that blocks until this function is done. The `async`-`await` pattern gives you the ability to write asynchronous non-blocking code that "looks" like simply synchronouse code.

Also I suggest you use the `Task.Run` function to spawn your tasks instead of the `TaskFactory`. It will spare from some problems later on. ;-)

Comment: Thank You for such fast answer, but unfortunately I get error `It is invalid to exclude specific continuation kinds for continuations off of multiple tasks.`

Comment: Ah... that happens if you don't read the documentation properly. Sorry this answer is wrong. Because the NotOn* and OnlyOn* options are illegal for this function. As it is the only idea I got is to maintain a list of the tasks you wait on and if the function triggers on a failed task you could remove this one and wait for the remaining.

Comment: Could You show some sample code? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Is there any explicit reason you want to use this schema? Or do you consider using the async-await pattern?

Comment: @Misiu I added some code to the answer that may give you a idea how to solve it. I wrote this in 2 minutes and I am not very good with C#. So please execute any mistakes there. I am more of a VB person.

Comment: The new code is racy because multiple handlers can complete at the same time. Also it has quadratic performance.

Comment: @usr You sure? I don't think multiple handlers are active at the same time. Because `ContinueWhenAny` only fires once, as soon as it encounters an task that finished and only for one task. So the a single `ContinueWhenAny` shouldn't result in more than one call of the `continuationFunction`

Comment: @Nitram I don't have any reasons behind this schema, I could use async await, but because I'm starting with those things I don't know how to use them.

Comment: @Misiu do you use .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: @Misiu Now this answer is slowly getting a bit long. I edited it to provide a async-await example. I highly recomment you also search the internet for some more examples how to use this. If you are using the latest .NET frameworks It is really a good idea to learn how to use this. It is much easier than to use the Task Continuations directly.

Comment: `If you are using the latest .NET frameworks It is really a good idea to learn how to use this` that is so correct. I think I must spend some time more on this async await thing. I'll check Your code right away, but it should work without any problems.

Comment: @Misiu Don't forget to mark one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can use `Task.WhenAny` to easily achieve what you want:

```
public async Task<int> GetFirstCompletedTaskAsync()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task> 
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return 1;
        }),
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            throw new Exception("My error");
        }),
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            return 3;
        }),
    };

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        if (finishedTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            return finishedTask
        }

        tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    }
    throw new WhateverException("No completed tasks");
}
```

Comment: I need slightly different version - I need to get first result from all tasks, but only from that task that completed. If all of them are faulted I want to throw exception.

Comment: This one has quadratic runtime in the number of tasks as well. Also quadratic memory consumption for the continuations.

Comment: @usr Do explain why this has quadric runtime and memory consumption?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov He tried to blame that on my answer too. ;-)

Comment: WhenAny hooks up continuations on all N tasks and the loop runs N times. In the other answer there were N Remove operations each of which take N/2 operations.

Comment: Is there a way to adopt this code for ASP.NET MVC? It gives random exception `[InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]` when you try to execute it while some previous tasks are not finished.

Comment: @AntonPapin The problem with MVC is you must wait for all tasks completion prior to the controller ending the session and returning the response. If you want to ignore that (which I don't recommend you do), you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run` which doesn't register continuations with the ASP.NET runtime. For more on that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805796/asp-net-controller-an-asynchronous-module-or-handler-completed-while-an-asynchr

Answer (score 2):

What if just simply do this (at least it worked for me):

```
        bool taskFinishedFlag = false;

        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(4000); return 1; });

        Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); 
                                                throw new Exception("");return 2; });

        Task t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(4000); return 3; });

        Task<int>[] Tasks = new[] { t1, t2, t3 };

        for (int i = 0; i < Tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            Tasks[i].ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    if (taskFinishedFlag) return;
                    taskFinishedFlag = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
        }
```

Comment: This is the best approach. Instead of writing to the console use a TaskCompletionSource to generate a task that can be awaited on.