# Error: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Controller Action method to Save user Details like below.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveUser(ViewModel.VM_CreateUser user)
{
    var result = await _user.Save(userDetails);
    return Json(new { Success = String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) });
}
```

So far there is no issue in above 4 lines function.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveUser(ViewModel.VM_CreateUser user)
{
    var result = await _user.Save(userDetails);
    new MailController().CreateUser(user.userDetails); //<==This is problem line of code.
}
```

and Below is my Mail Controller.

```
public class MailController : MailerBase
{
    public void CreateUser(ViewModel.VM_User user)
    {
        To.Add(user.EmailAddress);
        From = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSender"];
        Subject = "Hi";
        Email("CreateUser", user).DeliverAsync();
    }
}
```

in the above code, I am facing problem when I execute the Email Sending code. I get below error message.

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending

Please suggest the corrective action !!

Answer (score 8):

This is because `async` methods track their completion, even `async void`. They do this by registering with the `SynchronizationContext` when starting and marking the operation complete when returning. ASP.NET tracks all created operations and requires them to all be completed before your action returns, otherwise it returns an error to the HTTP client. If you need to run a “fire and forget” method, you must manually avoid launching it on the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`. For example, `await Task.Run(() => CallFireAndForget())` (`await` so that you wait for the synchronous portion to run on the thread pool. This works because `CallFireAndForget()` is `async void`. To fire a method which returns a `Task` as fire-and-forget, you have to explicitly avoid returning the `Task` to `Task.Run()` like this: `await Task.Run(() => { CallFireAndForgetAsync(); })`).

Another way to get the same error message to show up should be to write this in an asynchronous action:

```
// BAD CODE, DEMONSTRATION ONLY!
AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation();
```

If you use the `AsyncOperation` API, you have to ensure you call `AsyncOperation.OperationCompleted()` prior to allowing the action method to return.

In your case, if the mail sending is really intended to be a fire-and-forget task, you can do the following inside of `CreateUser` after changing its signature to `async Task CreateUserAsync(ViewModel.VM_User user)`:

```
await Task.Run(() => Email("CreateUser", user).DeliverAsync());
```

and in your action:

```
await new MailController().CreateUserAsync(user.userDetails);
```

Ideally, you wouldn’t use `Task.Run()` for something like this. Instead, you can temporarily replace the current `SynchronizationContext` instead (**NOTE WELL: Never `await` inside the `try{}`—instead, if you need to, store the `Task` in a local and await it after restoring the original `SynchronizationContext`** (it may be safer to use a primitive such as [`SynchronizationContextSwitcher.NoContext()`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.SynchronizationContextSwitcher/NoContext(System.Action)) ([source](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/76b27a3ee531554c0c81e55ab8425ac7caefaccb/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronizationContextSwitcher.cs#L46)) which does the right thing)):

```
var originalSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
try
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    new MailController().CreateUser(user.userDetails);
}
finally
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(originalSynchronizationContext);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does DeliverAsync return a Task? If it does, try this.

```
public class MailController : MailerBase
{
    public async Task CreateUserAsync(ViewModel.VM_User user)
    {
        To.Add(user.EmailAddress);
        From = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSender"];
        Subject = "Hi";
        await (Email("CreateUser", user).DeliverAsync());
    }
}
```

And then in your controller, await the task returned by CreateUserAsync.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveUser(ViewModel.VM_CreateUser user)
    {
        var result = await _user.Save(userDetails);
        await (new MailController().CreateUserAsync(user.userDetails)); 
        return Json(new { Success = String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) });
    }
```

note: If your goal is to make sending the email a background fire and forget operation, this is not it.

Comment: I am getting one compilation error. `Cannot await void`.

Comment: If DeliverAsync() returns void, then this wont work. Otherwise, did you change CreateUser to return a Task